# Laravel 5.3 relationship issue, Column not found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
class Company extends Model
{
 public function employees() {
    return $this->hasMany('Employee');   
}
}
class User extends Model
{
public function employee()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Employee');
}
}
class Employee extends Model
{
protected $table = "user_role_company";

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
public function company(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Company');
}
}
```

I get "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `companies` where `user_id` = 55)" when running:

Company::with('employees')->where('user_id',$user->id)->get();

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Where is your Schema? Are you trying to get employees belonging to a company for a particular user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it as:

```
Company::whereHas('employees', function($query) use($user) {
           $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
        })
        ->with('employees')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

use a `filter` on the `with` using a closure.

```
Company::with(['employees' => function($q) use($user) {
    return $q->where('user_id', $user->id);
}]);
```

Comment: this returns all the companies